# Check location of each button

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I have a frame that contains 81 buttons, lets say all the buttons contain no name, are all equal in size, and are all set automatically. So when I click one I would like to know which one is clicked. If I use a class that implements MouseListener and with this method

```
mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
temp[0]= e.getX();
temp[1]= e.getY();
}
```

How can I check with these coordinates?
Do I have to set each of the buttons with its own location to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
    public static final int BUTTONS_WIDTH_COUNT = 9;
    public static final int BUTTONS_HEIGHT_COUNT = 9;
    public static final Button[][] BUTTONS = new Button[BUTTONS_WIDTH_COUNT][BUTTONS_HEIGHT_COUNT]
    ...

    // I'll assume that the buttons are taking up the entire frame so no offsets are taken into account
    frame.addMouseListener(
        new MouseAdaptor() {
            mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // The X Y coordinates are relative to the component so
            int frameWidth = frame.getBounds().getWidth();
            int frameHeight = frame.getBounds().getHeight();

            Button buttonClicked = buttons[e.getX()/(frameWidth/BUTTONS_WIDTH_COUNT)][e.getY()/(frameHeight/BUTTONS_HEIGHT_COUNT)];
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Actually it will be a lot better to assign the same MouseAdaptor to all the buttons and use `e.getSource()` to know which button was invoking in the listener.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you. I would give you a +1 but I can't because I don't have enough rep yet :(

Comment: No problem. I think you can stil 'approve' the answer as the original poster.